# Dividir termo de pesquisa para ampliar resultados e ordenar resultados de acordo com o termo

Tags: php, mysql, algoritmo-de-busca

Digamos que eu tenha uma tabela chamada `carros`.
Nessa tabela tenho alguns carros registrados. Ex:

```
ID | Name    
1  | Corsa Amarelo
2  | Camaro 2 Portas Amarelo
3  | Camaro V12 Amarelo
4  | Camaro Esportivo Amarelo
5  | Fusca Amarelo
6  | Camaro Amarelo
7  | Gol Amarelo
8  | Ferrai Vermelha
9  | Ferrari 490 cv vermelha
```

Se eu usar a seguinte consulta `SELECT * FROM carros WHERE carros_name LIKE %camaro amarelo%` vou ter como resultado apenas a seguinte linha

```
6  | Camaro Amarelo
```

Se eu só dividir os termos da busca desse jeito `carros_name LIKE %camaro amarelo% OR carros_name LIKE %camaro% OR carros_name LIKE %amarelo%` o resultado vem todo misturado.

Porém eu gostaria obter como resultado tudo aquilo que tivesse as palavras do termo de pesquisa, organizando os resultados pelo termo mais parecido em diante. Algo como:

```
ID | Name
1  | Camaro Amarelo
4  | Camaro V12 Amarelo
5  | Camaro Esportivo Amarelo
3  | Camaro 2 Portas Amarelo    
2  | Corsa Amarelo
6  | Fusca Amarelo
7  | Gol Amarelo
```

Como pode observar no resultado acima, o resultado vem com uma classificação onde o termo buscado aparece primeiro, resultados com todas as palavras da busca em 2 segundo e por ultimo qualquer resultado que tenha alguma palavra do termo buscado.

Comment: Obs: 'rankear' não existe, o termo certo é `classificar` ou `ordenar`

Comment: Use o `match ... against` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) ao invés do `like`...

Comment: @Inkeliz isso resolveu! Muito obrigado! Se você formular uma resposta posso votar como a melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Porque não usa no final um "ORDER BY carros_name ASC"?
Assim ele ter retorna o resultado em ordem alfabética se e isso que quer.